# Error: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK Installed

Tags: java, android, version, javac

> Error: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK
>   installed. You can get it from:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads. Your
>   JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152;
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code
>   1)

My JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin;

ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;

Path: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;%JAVA_HOME%;C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\27.0.0;C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;

Any idea why returns me this error when i try to use ionic cordova run android?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should contain just one entry, pointing to the root directory of the JRE/JDK. In your case, `JAVA_HOME` should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152`

Comment: Thank you! Works...

Comment: I had this error randomly appear after building for Apache Cordova targeting my physical android device. Disconnecting and reconnecting the physical device annoyingly fixed the issue :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Search for "edit environment variables" in start.
and under user variables add a new variable with name "JAVA_HOME" and value with path_to_jdk_bin.

like this

[image]

Now under system variables, the path variable should contain(add if not added) the entry %JAVA_HOME%.

Like this

[image]

Comment: JAVA_HOME should not include the bin directory, just the JDK root folder.

Comment: In order for it to work for me, I had to include the bin folder in the path and not just the root folder as @andreszs addressed.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly  make sure you don't have multiple java versions installed

Once you're done with that open Environment Variables tab under My computers

Create a new user variable and name it PATH

Set the user variable value as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin(may change depending on where you have installed java)

open cmd type javac

This should be enough to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure this out and just found a solution I haven't seen elsewhere.

I noticed I had a second version of Java installed in my `Program Files (x86)` directory.

Pointing the variables to that location instead, ie `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

In VS, open Tools menu and select Options.

In Tools for Apache Cordova select  Environment Variable Overrides .

Select JAVA_HOME checkbox and browse for JDK directory.

[image: Cordova Environment Variable Overrides]