# Ionic: Your JAVA_HOME is invalid

Tags: java-home

I am facing `JAVA_HOME` invalid problem.

I have followed these steps:

1. `npm install -g cordova ionic`
2. `ionic start myApp tabs`
3. `cordova platfomr add android`
4. Installed JDK jdk1.8.0_91
5. Set `JAVA_HOME` path as `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin"` in `Environment variables`

But I am still getting this error: [Error: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040598/error-failed-to-run-javac-version-make-sure-that-you-have-a-jdk-installed)

Comment: can you check it in command prompt java command

Comment: Actually you have to put "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin" in PATH variable so it will be accessible from the prompt.

Comment: @Utpaul I have cheked java command its working

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have to put "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin" in PATH variable so it will be accessible from the prompt.