# Error: Failed to build android apk using ionic3

Tags: ionic3

Error: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

Comment: Possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040598/error-failed-to-run-javac-version-make-sure-that-you-have-a-jdk-installed) for you!

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall your JDK, your JAVA_HOME path seems correct. and Please follow [ionic_ publishing_guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html)

you will get all the steps here, and it's very easy to follow